# Aligning Two-Column List Items

Tags: css

I'm working on a menu that needs to be two columns. I've been able to accomplish this but one of the requirements for this menu is, if there is an uneven number of items in each column, the last one should be aligned to the right column.

This is fairly similar to this question I guess. My `ul` is floated to the right, my `li` are floated to the left. Floating the `li` to the right achieves my desired appearance but, as expected, the links are out of order.

Is there a way I could accomplish this without JS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `:nth-last-child()` and `:nth-child()` should do the trick. Using the code below you select the last child only if it's odd and `float` it right.

```css
li { width: 50%; display: inline-block; }
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) { float: right; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li><!--
  --><li>2</li><!--
  --><li>3</li><!--
  --><li>4</li><!--
  --><li>5</li><!--
  --><li>6</li><!--
  --><li>7</li><!--
  --><li>8</li><!--
  --><li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, in order to avoid using floats :

```css
li { width: 50%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
ul { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li><!--
  --><li>2</li><!--
  --><li>3</li><!--
  --><li>4</li><!--
  --><li>5</li><!--
  --><li>6</li><!--
  --><li>7</li><!--
  --><li>8</li><!--
  --><li>9</li>
</ul>
```